# SessionScope não está vindo no Request

Tags: jsf, java-ee

Tenho uma bean para fazer login, quando tento pegar ela no request da classe do filtro ela esta vindo null. As informações que estão vindo no console são essas.

```
17:29:57,968 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
17:29:57,968 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) SETANDO O BOOLEAN DO    LOGIN E REDIRECIONANDO PARA O INDEX
17:29:57,968 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) USERNAME teste
17:29:57,969 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) PASSWORD teste
 17:29:57,969 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) BOOLEAN true
 17:29:57,969 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
17:29:57,969 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
17:29:57,975 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
17:29:57,975 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
17:29:57,975 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) org.jboss.weld.context.conversation.ConversationIdGenerator
17:29:57,976 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) org.jboss.weld.context.ConversationContext.conversations
17:29:57,976 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) org.jboss.weld.context.ignore.guard.marker
17:29:57,976 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
17:29:57,976 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
17:29:57,976 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) BEAN null OU BOOLEAN LOOGIN = null
17:29:57,976 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
17:29:57,976 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1)     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Bean

```
@ManagedBean(name="login")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7765876811740798583L;

private boolean loggedIn;

private String userName;
private String passWord;

@Inject private LoginRepository loginRepository;



private UIComponent component; 

public String loginControl() {

    if (loginRepository.userLogin(userName, passWord) ) {
        this.loggedIn = true;

        System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
        System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
        System.out.println("SETANDO O BOOLEAN DO LOGIN E REDIRECIONANDO PARA O INDEX");
        System.out.println("USERNAME " + this.userName);
        System.out.println("PASSWORD " + this.passWord);
        System.out.println("BOOLEAN " + this.loggedIn);
        System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
        System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");

        return "/secured/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.addMessage(component.getClientId(),new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Erro", "Usuário ou Senha Incorreto."));
    return "/login.xhtml";

}


public String efetuaLogoff() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().remove("userName");
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    session.invalidate();
    this.loggedIn = false;
    return "/login.xhtml";
}


public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}


public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}


public String getPassWord() {
    return passWord;
}


public void setPassWord(String passWord) {
    this.passWord = passWord;
}

public UIComponent getComponent() {
    return component;
}

public void setComponent(UIComponent component) {
    this.component = component;
}

public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    return loggedIn;
}

public void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn) {
    this.loggedIn = loggedIn;
}
```

}

LoginFilter

```
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

/**
 * Checks if user is logged in. If not it redirects to the login.xhtml page.
 */
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // Get the loginBean from session attribute
    LoginBean loginBean = (LoginBean)((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getAttribute("login");

    Enumeration<String> name = request.getAttributeNames();

    System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
    System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
    for(Enumeration<String> n = name; n.hasMoreElements();)
        System.out.println(n.nextElement());
    // For the first application request there is no loginBean in the
    // session so user needs to log in
    // For other requests loginBean is present but we need to check if user
    // has logged in successfully
    if (loginBean == null || !loginBean.isLoggedIn()) {
        System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
        System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
        System.out.println("BEAN " + loginBean + " OU BOOLEAN LOOGIN = " + loginBean);
        System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
        System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");

        String contextPath = ((HttpServletRequest) request)
                .getContextPath();
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(contextPath
                + "/login.xhtml");
    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response);

}

public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    // Nothing to do here!
}

public void destroy() {
    // Nothing to do here!
}
```

}

Comment: João, tem certeza que a sessão não está sendo invalidada após o login? Esta é uma técnica comum para evitar alguns ataques à segurança do sistema.

Comment: @utluiz ate onde eu sei não, mas como posso confirmar isso?

Comment: @João, porque acha que acessar a chave do nome do Bean irá recuperá-lo? O `@SessionScoped` não significa que o `Bean` vai estar na sessão (Isso significa, que sempre que acessar esse Bean, usando CDI, ele será sempre a mesma instância para um usuário/sessão, por isso é escopo de sessão). Além disso está misturando anotações do JSF com anotações do CDI, talvez valha a pena trocar o `@ManagedBead` pelo `@Named`, não sendo obrigatório claro.

Comment: @Walkim
certo, sendo o `bean` sempre a mesma instância por que não consigo recuperar ele para poder usar no `doFilter`, como eu coloquei no código acima, o `Request` não esta trazendo ele, e preciso dele para controlar a sessão =/

Comment: @João, o problema é que o ServletFilter é executado antes do contexto do JSF. O certo seria fazer injeção do Bean no filtro, porém é capaz de mesmo usando um @Inject, isso não funcionar. Como eu ainda não usei bem a CDI não sei se funcionaria mesmo com o CDI sendo gerenciado pelo Weld. Um workaround se o @Inject não funcionar seria descobrir como o JSF guarda os `Beans` de sessão e tentar recuperar. Ou então porque não guarda um `boolean` na sessão ao invés de usar um `Bean`?

Comment: @Walkim
Ok vou tentar, obrigado pela sugestão.

Comment: @Wakim Também fiquei cismado com esses pontos. O que não entendo é que há uma [resposta "canônica" do BalusC](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2633733/1683070) que diz ser perfeitamente possível.

Comment: @utluiz, acho que essa solução do BalusC é só para jsf, fiz um teste usando CDI e não funcionou. com CDI,  consegui injetar um Bean num `Filter` usando o `@Inject` e na sessão ele coloca o bean com uma chave auto-gerada dele. Não cheguei a testar com jsf. O CDI eu suspeitava que iria funcionar, já que é gerenciado pelo container.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi o problema da seguinte forma.

Adicionei a variável `loggedIn` na sessão quando o usuário é logado, e no filter pego essa variável pelo `request` que recebo.
Não sei se é a melhor forma de se fazer, mas foi uma solução que achei.

Bean

```
public String loginControl() {

    if (loginRepository.userLogin(userName, passWord) ) {
        this.loggedIn = true;

        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) fc.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        session.setAttribute("loggedIn", this.loggedIn);

        return "/secured/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.addMessage(component.getClientId(),new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Erro", "Usuário ou Senha Incorreto."));
    return "/login.xhtml";

}
```

Filter

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // Get the loginBean from session attribute
    //LoginBean loginBean = (LoginBean)((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getAttribute("login");
    Boolean loggedIn = false;

    try {
        loggedIn = (Boolean)((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getAttribute("loggedIn");
    }catch(NullPointerException e){
        System.out.println("Problema ao tentar logar.************************** erro " + e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("loggedIn = " + loggedIn);
    }

    if (loggedIn == null || !loggedIn) {

        String contextPath = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getContextPath();
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(contextPath + "/login.xhtml");
    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response);

}
```